# UDF Regex - yyyy only

Tags: regex, vba

I am just learning some regex, and I need help spitting out matches generated by my regex code. I found some very useful resources here to output anything not matched, but I want to output only the parts of a cell that do match. I am looking for dates in cells, that may be a single yyyy date or yyyy-yy, or the like (as shown from the sample data below).

Sample data:

```
1951/52
1909-13
2005-2014
7 . (1989)-
1 (1933/34)-2 (1935/36)
1979-2012/2013
```

Current Function Code: (A snippet found from an existing post here, but returns the replacement value instead of what was matched)

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "([12][0-9]{3}[/][0-9]{2,4})|([12][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{2,4})|([12][0-9]{3})"
```

Comment: Did you use `.Replace`? You need `.Execute`.

Comment: I haven't. I am looking at an example using .Execute instead, which does seem to be what I need to use. Trying to figure out how to implement.

Comment: Are [these values matched correctly](https://regex101.com/r/hZ2qT7/1)? Or better [look at this one - `[12][0-9]{3}(?:[/-][0-9]{2,4})?`](https://regex101.com/r/hZ2qT7/2). Or even enclose with `\b`: [`\b[12][0-9]{3}(?:[/-][0-9]{2,4})?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/hZ2qT7/3).

Comment: Looking at the regex tester from your hyperlink, the only thing that isn't matched exactly is the last line, 1979-2012/2013. I have been trying to piece together all instances that will match, and if what you have provided is more accurate, I will definitely use it. Thank you. My alternative is to manually remove characters/numbers that aren't needed in every excel cell (roughly 10k), so I am trying my best to use regex, unless there is an alternative.

Comment: Ok, does this - [`\b[12][0-9]{3}(?:[/-][0-9]{2,4})*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/hZ2qT7/4) - return all what you need?

Comment: Almost, I have one more instance: 1951,52. Can the above be modified to add?

Comment: Sure - [`\b[12][0-9]{3}(?:[,/-][0-9]{2,4})*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/hZ2qT7/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b[12][0-9]{3}(?:[,/-][0-9]{2,4})*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ2qT7/5)

**Note** that `\b` might be removed if you are not interested in a whole word search.

*Pattern details*:

- `\b` - leading word boundary (the preceding char must be either a non-word char or the start of string)
- `[12][0-9]{3}` - `1` or `2` followed with any 3 digits
- `(?:[,/-][0-9]{2,4})*` - zero or more sequences (`(?:...)*`) of:

  - `[,/-]` - a `,`, `/` or `-` characters
  - `[0-9]{2,4}` - any 2 to 4 digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary (there must be a non-word char or the end of string after).

Sample VBA code to grab all those values using `RegExp#Execute`:

```
Sub FetchDateLikeStrs()
Dim cellContents As String
Dim reg As regexp
Dim mc As MatchCollection
Dim m As match

Set reg = New regexp
reg.pattern = "\b[12][0-9]{3}(?:[,/-][0-9]{2,4})*\b"
reg.Global = True

cellContents = "1951/52 1909-13  2005-2014  7 . (1989)-  1 (1933/34)-2 (1935/36) 1979-2012/2013  1951,52"
Set mc = reg.Execute(cellContents)
For Each m In mc
 Debug.Print m.Value
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Having some difficulties converting this sub into a UDF. Trying to use Function FetchDates(data As String) As String. Then where Cell Contents = "arbitrary value", I replaced that with data.

Comment: Cell contents is the Cell.Value (a string). The result must also be a string. You might want to concat the match values found using any separator you want.